# R - moderated mediation using the lavaan package

Tags: r, interaction, mediation, lavaan

I am interested in determining the conditional indirect effects of `X` on `Y` at a series of values for a third variable `Z`.

I was able to use the `lavaan` package to calculate some initial indirect effects based of the syntax available in this post: [Multiple mediation analysis in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19599/multiple-mediation-analysis-in-r)

However, I do not know how to access an output of values for conditional indirect effects once I add the interaction term into the equation.

Any support or suggestions for other packages to use would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I posted this question in another location and was provided the answer by Terry Jorgenson.  Question and answer:

*I would like to calculate the conditional indirect effects of `X` on `Y` given a set of values for the moderator `W`.  Both `X` and the moderator are continuous.  Could you provide some direction for structuring the model syntax?*

Assuming `X` and `W` are both observed variables, you can calculate the product term `XW` in your data.frame and simply add the product term (`X-W` interaction) to the models for `M` and `Y` in Yves' example earlier in this thread (but a single-group version, since your moderator is continuous).

```
model <- ' 
  Y ~ c*X + cw*XW + b*M
  M ~ a*X + aw*XW
  ## indirect and total effects, conditional on W == 0
  ab0 := a*b            # + 0*aw*b
  total0 := ab0 + c     # + 0*cw
  ## indirect and total effects, conditional on W == 1
  ab1 := ab0 + 1*aw*b
  total1 := ab1 + c + 1*cw
  ## indirect and total effects, conditional on W == 2
  ab2 := ab0 + 2*aw*b
  total2 := ab2 + c + 2*cw
'
```

This is specifically designed to assess conditional indirect effects using the [`lavaan` package](http://lavaan.ugent.be/).

Comment: Is it a mistake that the equations for Y and M include the interaction without also including the main effect of the moderator (W)?

Comment: Here is a helpful comparison of moderated mediation output from Haye's PROCESS macro for SPSS and lavaan (scroll down for model 7): https://nickmichalak.blogspot.com/2016/07/reproducing-hayess-process-models.html It looks like it does indeed need both main effects (X and W) in addition to their interaction.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be edited to reflect @RoseHartman's comment ?