# Moderated mediation with latent variables

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am trying to make a moderated mediation, where the moderator (W) is categorical and Y and X are latent variables. However, none of the approaches I found either [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163436/r-moderated-mediation-using-the-lavaan-package) or in [Pubmed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=Moderated+mediation+analysis%3A+an+illustration+using+the+association+of+gender+with+delinquency+and+mental+health).

Please consider the model from the paper linked:

[image]

Whose specification looks like:

```
> model7 <- “
+  del ~ cprime * male
+  del ~ b * respect
+  del ~ bprime * maleXResp
+  respect ~ a * male
+  respect ~~ maleXResp
+  male ~~ maleXResp
+
+  bmale:= b + bprime
+  indMale:= bmale * a
+  indFemale:= b * a
+  indDiff:= indMale – indFemale
+  ”
>
> fit7 <- sem(model7, data=d, fixed.x=FALSE,
+      se=“bootstrap”)
> summary(fit7)
```

Full citation for this paper is:

```
Jeremy N.V Miles, Magdalena Kulesza, Brett Ewing, Regina A Shih, Joan S Tucker, Elizabeth J D'Amico, (2015) "Moderated
mediation analysis: an illustration using the association of gender with delinquency and mental health", Journal of Criminal
Psychology, Vol. 5 Issue: 2, pp.99-123, https://doi.org/10.1108/JCP-02-2015-0010
```

In the data I have access to, both Deliquency and Respect are latent variables.

- How would I specify the mediation in the case where deliquency and respect are latent variables?

In my attempt, lavaan complains of Respect not being an observed variable, I can't figure out how to approach this issue.

Comment: As specified/depicted, there's no indirect/mediated effect--you're only depicting the interaction between Male and Respect on Delinquency. Male can't serve as *both* a moderator and a predictor of a mediator within the same model, if that's what you were trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and it is quite simple, but introduces new assumptions to the analysis.

One can create a multiplicative term using `indProd()` from `semTools()` like this:

```
dataset<-indProd(dataset, var1=c("item1","item2","item3"),
                      var2=c("second1","second2","second3"))
```

And then create a latent variable that regresses on this term:

```
model7 <- '
    ...
    interaction =~ item1.second1 + item2.second2 + item3.second3
    ...
'
```

The remainder of the model is similar to the one in the question, using a mediation approach but including `interaction`.

Comment: You might also consider a multiple groups approach.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyMiles , I wanted to learn this particular type of specification.